# Can't post list of object to a web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

What am i doing wrong here (i'm using .net core 3.1):

**Object:**

```
   public class Member
    {
        public int NUM {get;set;}
    }
```

**Post Action**

```
     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] IEnumerable<Member> members)
```

**JSON**

```
{
    [
        {"NUM": 5},
        {"NUM": 4}
    ]
}
```

**Error i'm getting from Postman**

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|fc86d5d0-498dec466e59f3c5.",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TRS.Gemini.MemberApi.Controllers.Member]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to post a single object rather than a collection and that worked fine. The object in the end of course will be a lot more complex but i wanted to start simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the object you've defined, the valid JSON input would be:

```
[
    {"NUM": 5},
    {"NUM": 4}
]
```

Note the lack of { } brackets.

The payload you've specified is also not valid JSON.